# Why does /tmp/emacs${UID}/server get stale after last emacsclient exits?

Tags: linux, emacs, emacsclient

With GNU Emacs 23.2.1, that I installed from sources on 2 different GNU/Linux distributions (CentOS 4.x, and Ubuntu Hardy - both with KDE 3.x)

I do:

```
$ emacs --daemon
("emacs")
Starting Emacs daemon.
$ emacsclient -c
Waiting for Emacs...
```

Emacs starts as expected. Then I close the client. `fuser /tmp/emacs${UID}/server` indicates that the socket is alive, and the `emacs --daemon` process is running.

```
$ emacsclient -c
Waiting for Emacs...
```

Emacs does not start. `fuser /tmp/emacs${UID}/server` indicates that the socket is stale, and the `emacs --daemon` process no longer exists. And so:

```
$ emacsclient -c
emacsclient: connect: Connection refused
emacsclient: No socket or alternate editor.  Please use:

        --socket-name
        --server-file      (or environment variable EMACS_SERVER_FILE)
        --alternate-editor (or environment variable ALTERNATE_EDITOR)
```

When I keep at least one client running, I can open and close as many other clients I wish.

**So my questions are:**

1. Can anybody else see this behavior?
2. Is there a way to keep the socket alive even after the last client exits?
3. Is there a good way to check if the socket will allow opening another client?
4. Why does the socket stays around if it can no longer be used?

---

Edit: It seems that `emacs --daemon` segfaults. I posted it as [bug 7149](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=7149)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anybody else see this behavior?

Yes, though my working style is different. I have (server-start) in my .emacs file instead of using command line arguments.

> Is there a way to keep the socket alive even after the last client exits?

Are you using **C-x #** to close client buffers cleanly?

> Is there a way to keep the socket alive even after the last client exits?

I find that I have to **M-x server-start** on an Emacs that has been up for a couple of days or more. It is not exactly keeping it alive, but re-creating it.

> Why does the socket stays around if it can no longer be used?

I believe this is a bug.

Comment: 1. Thanks for the confirmation; Can you please describe your work-flow beside using `(server-start)`? 2. No, but even if so, it does not seem to help. Nor exiting with `C-x 5 0`; 3. Don't thing it apply. 4. I'll check if this bug is reported.

Comment: The other half of my workflow is a bash alias for emacsclient that redirects I/O and puts emacsclient quietly into the background when launching the new buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this problem by deleting the directory containing the socket. I ran:

```
strace emacsclient -c
```

and saw these lines:

```
stat("/tmp/emacs1000/server", {st_mode=S_IFSOCK|0700, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/tmp/emacs1000/server"}, 23) = -1 ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

which show the directory where the socket file is located, then all I had to do was delete this directory:

```
rm -rf /tmp/emacs1000
```